# SuiteScript Auto Populate Department Line Item Fields

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

[Code Portion Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH9rj.jpg)[image]

I am trying to populate the Department line item field as per the Department Transaction Body Field, please assist to check if my codes are right.. i am new to suitescript.

```
var itemDepartment = nlapiGetFieldValue('department');
var nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue = nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'department_display', itemDepartment);
```

It keeps stating that `department_display` is not an internal ID.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The id of the department column field is also department, same as the header field.
Therefore, the second line of you snippet should be:

```
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','department',itemDepartment);
```

**EDIT**
As per the comment below, please find below the full code snippet to populate lines department from the customer on before submit:

```
    function onBeforeSubmit(type) {
           if (type == 'create' || type == 'edit') {
               var customerId = nlapiGetFieldValue('entity');
                var itemDepartment = nlapiLookupField('customer',customerId, 'custentity_department');
                var itemCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
                for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
                    nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'department', i, itemDepartment);

                }
            }

      }
```

Also, as a side note, you don't have to load the whole record in order to get a field value. You should use nlapiLookupField instead. It's much faster, safer and less api usage.

Comment: hey, thanks for your comment. i tried to put 'department' but it didnt populate the field as well.

Comment: please click on Code Portion Click Here

Comment: As I understand you are trying to populate the department lines from the header on before submit.

nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue API is applicable only on focused lines, which is not relevant to your case.
I have added a full code snippet to my original answer.

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment. this works with slight tweaks! thank you so much!

Comment: No problem,
You can mark this answer as the right answer so that this topic will appear as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting text instead,if it is a client script.
The id of the department column field is 'department'

var itemDepartment = nlapiGetFieldText('department');

nlapiSetCurrentLineItemText('item', 'department', itemDepartment);

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. this is an User Event Script and this did not populate the line item field.. :(