# SuiteScript auto-populate line item fields from header fields

Tags: suitescript

I am trying to have the class field for each line item on a Sales Order be automatically populated to match the class field set on the header level of that Sales Order.  I tried following the article "[SuiteScript Auto Populate Department Line Item Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465539/suitescript-auto-populate-department-line-item-fields)" and making some adjustments, but it does not populate the class field for each line item.  I am using a User Event script and trying to populate Before Submit.  Here is the code I am using:

```
function onBeforeSubmit(type) {
if (type == 'create' || type =='edit'){
    var itemClass = nlapiGetFieldValue('class');
    var itemCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
    for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
        nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'class', itemClass);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'class', itemClass)
```

is missing a parameter for the line number.  This should be the correct API call

```
nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'class',i, itemClass)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!!  Now when setting the Class on the main line level of a Sales Order this script will copy the same class to all line items on the sales order.  Perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

This worked as user event script.

```
 function onBeforeSubmit(type) {
if (type == 'create' || type =='edit'){
    var itemClass = nlapiGetFieldValue('class');
    var itemCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
    for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
        nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'class', i, itemClass);
    }
}
```